# Unable to Filter a product in online website using selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a scenario, where I can login into Flipkart website, login into Mobiles section and Filtering products.

While I am trying to filtering the products, it is throwing error message like "Unable to find element"

Any help is appreciated

Please find the below code that I am using:

```
Action mov;
Actions b;

WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();

//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\Users\\Murthy\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32(1)\\chromedriver.exe");
//WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();

d.get("https://www.flipkart.com");

d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

d.manage().window().maximize();

b = new Actions(d);
mov = b.moveToElement(d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).build();
mov.perform();

d.findElement(By.className("_3ZgIXy")).click();

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
je.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)"," " );

//This is for clicking on More button under Brand Filter
WebElement e = d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/section/div[2]/div[2]/span/span[3]"));
b.moveToElement(e).click().perform();

//d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();

//JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
//j.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)"," " );

String parentwindow = d.getWindowHandle();
d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]"));

//System.out.println(" Parent window text" + parentwindow);

for (String winhandle : d.getWindowHandles()) {
    d.switchTo().window(winhandle);
}

d.findElement(By.className("_1p7h2j")).click();
```

Comment: Use webdriver wait to make your script to wait for the element to be loaded in the page. Also can you mention at which line your are getting the error.

Comment: i am getting error at the line  'd.findelement(By.classname("_1p7h2j")).click() ' , as I am trying to select a product and filter with that

Comment: How you fixed the problem ? I am also facing similar one now.